# Адаптивная сетка шестиугольников с раздвигающимися половинками

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Можно ли придать всем  изображениям форму шестиугольника в адаптивной сетке?

```
<div>
    <img src="link" class="Image">
</div>

<div>
    <img src="link" class="Image">
</div>
...
```

Я нашел несколько способов сделать это, но мне нужно было заполнить изображение в коде CSS.

Эти способы не подходят  для меня, потому что веб-сайт загружает случайные изображения из Интернета с помощью `jQuery`, поэтому я не могу использовать фоновые изображения.

Моя попытка здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/8f5m5wv0/

Comment: Проголосовал, подписался, что еще сделать?))

Comment: Ни за что не бросайте! Понятное дело, что можно полезняшки заценить на сайте, вашем, или любого другого специалиста, но за всеми не набегаешься)) Да и сообществу полезнее такие "само-ответы". Другое дело, что их никак нельзя выделить из-за особенностей платформы.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/26114920/7394871

Answer (score 4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Техника создания респонсивных шестиугольников использует:

- `<img>` тег
- неупорядоченный список: каждый шестиугольник содержится в теге `<li>`
  и теге `<a>`
- `transform rotate` и `skew`, чтобы сделать шестиугольник
- `nth-child()` для размещения шестиугольников в правильном порядке

И еще, чтобы создать **шестиугольную сетку** с тегом `<img>`.

### Особенности сетки шестиугольника:

- Сетка респонсивна, так как основана на процентах ширины.
- Шестиугольники сохраняют свои пропорции с помощью метода
  [padding-bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div), а размеры изображений изменяются в соответствии с
  формой шестиугольника.
  **Эффект наведения на шестиугольники**: текст скользит с прозрачным наложением на изображение.
- Каждый шестиугольник поддерживает свои границы: эффект наведения (или
  событие щелчка) для каждого шестиугольника срабатывает только внутри
  фактической формы.

### Полный код

Следующий фрагмент не является последней версией сетки. [Репозиторий GitHub](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) поддерживается и обновляется. Вопросы и вклады могут быть сделаны там.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(123, 158, 158);
}

#hexGrid {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0.707% 0;
}

#hexGrid:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.hex {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hex * {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}

.hexIn {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
            transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* HEX CONTENT */

.hex img {
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hex h1, .hex p {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    background-color: #008080;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
            transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}

.hex h1 {
    bottom: 110%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.hex h1:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hex p {
    padding-top: 50%;
    top: 110%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

.hexIn:hover h1 {
    bottom: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.hexIn:hover p {
    top: 50%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

/* SPACING AND SIZING */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
    .hex {
        width: 19.2%; /* = (100-4) / 5 */
        padding-bottom: 22.170%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9) {
        margin-top: -4.676%;
        margin-bottom: -4.676%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+10) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+ 7) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+3),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
    .hex {
        width: 24.25%; /* = (100-3) / 4 */
        padding-bottom: 28.001%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7) {
        margin-top: -6.134%;
        margin-bottom: -6.134%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+3) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+8) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5) {
        clear: left;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
    .hex {
        width: 32.666%; /* = (100-2) / 3 */
        padding-bottom: 37.720%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5) {
        margin-top: -8.564%;
        margin-bottom: -8.564%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+6) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .hex {
        width: 49.5%; /* = (100-1) / 2 */
        padding-bottom: 57.158%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-top: -13.423%;
        margin-bottom: -13.423%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,800italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,300,200,100,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Изменение количества шестиугольников в строке

Сетка адаптирует количество шестиугольников в строке в соответствии с шириной области просмотра от `5` на экранах шире, чем `1200px`, до `2` на экранах, меньших `600px.`

Если вам не нужны медиа-запросы, а просто нужно изменить количество шестиугольников в строке, вы можете убрать CSS из соответствующего медиа-запроса и удалить ненужные.

Для получения дополнительной настройки см. [sizing and spacing of hexagons](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons#spacing-and-sizing-calculations).

### Демо

Список всех демонстраций см. В этой коллекции codepen: [Responsive grids of hexagons](http://codepen.io/collection/npgxpm/) с различным количеством шестиугольников в строке, варианты центрирования и многое другое ...

Вот оригинальная [демонстрационная программа](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd) на `codepen` с элементом `.pusher` для создания неправильной сетки из шестиугольников. Элемент `.pusher` используется для создания "дырок" в сетке с пустыми шестиугольниками.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о сотах, то для пчелиного шестигранника здесь есть возможность сделать это с помощью CSS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <div><! -  div получает отрицательное нижнее `margin`. И все они получают отрицательный правый `margin` ->
      <span> <!-- скручивание и вращение -->
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1"/><!-- поворот назад, `unskewed` и `rescaled` -->
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  margin:0 0;
  height:180px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:-51px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div span {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  height:110%;
  width:100%;
  top:-5%;
  left:0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px;
  background:blue;
  transform:rotate(45.5deg) skew(16.5deg,15.5deg);  
}
div span img {
  transform:rotate(-45deg) skew(0,0) scale(1.4,0.77) ;
}
img {
  vertical-align:bottom;
  border:solid;
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-bottom:2px;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
  margin-bottom:-179px;
}
section {
  width:920px;
  margin:auto;
  background:linear-gradient(to top right , pink,gray,lime,purple,yellow);
  padding:1px 51px 90px 1px;
}
body {
  background:#333;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/7"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/8"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/2"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/3"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/4"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/5"/>
    </span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/6"/>
    </span>
  </div>  

  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/9"/>
    </span>
  </div>  
  <div>
    <span>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/10"/>
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Источник ответа:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024892/7394871) @G-Cyr